# How to make List<Object> variable appear in DataBinding UI when using WPF in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm in the process of learning WPF and currently exploring data binding. I have a `DataGrid` control on my form, and in my C# code for the form I have a `List<string>` variable.

I want to be able to use the Properties UI for the `DataGrid` in the designer to bind the `List<string>` to the `DataGrid`. I cannot figure out what I need to do or where I need to look in the UI to do this.

This is what I am doing:

1. Click my `DataGrid` in the UI designer to make it the active control.
2. Move to the `Properties` window.
3. Scroll down to the `ItemsSource` property.
4. Click on the field and the UI with Source, Path, Converter and Options pops up.

And when I get to this point I no longer know what to do.

**I do not want to accomplish this by writing/modifying XAML. I want to know how it works using the UI.**

Comment: I take it you would not like to do it programatically either?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring If I have to modify some of the underlying C# to allow me to use the UI to do the binding, that's fine. But I just want to use the UI to accomplish the actual binding.

Comment: Is there a particular reason as to why you want to do this through the designer?

Comment: XAML pisses me off and I will be less resistant to learning and accepting it this way. I also prefer clicking things to typing things when possible.

Comment: @paqogomez If all you're going to do is make snide comments, and then go to my other months old posts and make more snide comments, go elsewhere please.

Comment: Not interested in feedback on what methodology to use. I know how I learn best. I will learn relevant XAML best if I can use the designer to show me how it generates it first.

Comment: I think that is a good way to start learning it, and I really think you will be surprised to see you actually start to pick it up, and yes even prefer XAML over designer. No one says you can't do both, I still do, because I am still learning too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having never used the designer before, I can't be totally sure (your use case isn't quite clear either).

That being said, in my designer you

1. Set the "Binding Type" to "Data Context"
2. Select the "Custom" text box (needed for me because it doesn't see my DataContext)
3. Type the name of your **property** in the "Path" field (you can only bind to Properties)
4. Hit OK.

Note that this is the same as writing in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemCollection}"/>
<!-- or --!>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MytItemsCollection}"/>
```

There's a reason no one uses the designer....

The other options are more "advanced" binding concepts that you don't normally use on ItemsSource properties.

Note that `DataGrid` is a poor choice for displaying strings. `ListView` or `ListBox` are much better choices, as they don't assume your information has multiple pieces (like `DataGrid` does).

Comment: I have no "Binding Type" option. I have Source, Path, Converter, Options. Selecting DataContext in Source does not give me any "Custom" text box anywhere. Is this because I'm using VS 2010?

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone, Thats quite possible. In your case I would just set the "Path" variable to the name of your property.

Comment: I don't understand this part: "You can only bind to Properties" and subsequent remarks about properties. My `List` is not a Property of anything. It is just a variable I have declared in the underlying C# for the window.

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone For binding to work, you have to set an object as the "DataContext" for your page/control. This object is typically referred to as a "ViewModel". Public properties of that object (and only that object) can then be bound to. A common way to do this is to just write `DataContext = new MyViewModel()` in code-behind. To use a property of the underlying C#, write `DataContext = this;`. Note this is considered bad practice in WPF, as it violates MVVM.

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone Note that this is one reason to use XAML, it doesn't change much (I actually haven't encountered any) in different versions of VS.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know you're trying to help but none of what you're saying makes any sense to me at all and it's very frustrating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55876/discussion-between-bradleydotnet-and-jdinklage-morgoone).

Answer (score 2):

I understand not liking XAML, as it really intimidated me at first, but I will quickly say that it is a powerful tool. I am not sure how to do it through the designer, but in C# let's say you name your DataGrid 'myDataGrid' and your List is named 'stringList'. It is as simple as the following:

```
  myDataGrid.ItemsSource = stringList;
```

and the data grid is now bound to your string list.

Comment: Why does this just add rows with the Length of each string in the List instead of the string itself?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (as you noted). @JdinklageMorgoone, That depends on the way you set up the columns. You don't normally bind `string` variables to a `DataGrid`

Comment: `string` is just a shortcut example I'm using to understand how binding a `List` works. How do I need to set up the columns and why does AutoGenerateColumns property not do this?

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone, Try binding to an object instead, or use something other than `DataGrid`. If I had to guess, `DataGrid` isn't set up very well to deal with primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking the question! The properties window is so underrated. 
First you must set the DataContext.
It's in the common section of the properties window. Set the data context to whatever view model you need. If you don't have a VM and the List is in the code behind, set the data context to relative source self.
Next in the Path write the name of your List.
Also, you may want to use ObservableCollection instead of List so your objects are updated in the UI as they change.

Comment: Actually the properties window is very overrated :) The last time I used it in a WPF app was, well, never. In WinForms its very useful though. Its much faster to just type the XAML (especially with Intellisense). Plus your layouts are much more flexible/automatic. Setting a bazillion margins is *not* the right way to do a UI in WPF (which is what happens when you use the visual margins).

Comment: Setting a bazillion margins. how can I argue with that :)

Comment: Disagree. Doing UI design via writing code instead of visually is incredibly irritating to me.

Comment: @ClevelandBuckeye Thank you for you response. I don't have the options you are asking me to set. I don't know what a View Model is, and nothing I choose lets me pick my List variable as defined in the C# code for the form.

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone Have you actually *looked* at the XAML the designer produces? Compare that with any one who knows what they are doing. Then compare how they work. The handcrafted version will be much more resistant to screen-resizing (among other benefits). WPF is meant to be *coded*. Its a declarative UI. I understand it irritates you, but you are shooting yourself in the foot by saying "I refuse to use XAML". WPF is so much more powerful if you use it as intended.

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone Aside from that, there are features of WPF (Animations, DataTemplates, Styles, and Triggers come to mind) that would be a *nightmare* to write in any kind of designer. I wouldn't even want to try (assuming its even possible).

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone If you have a friend of knows WPF/XAML, he may be able to help with the first problem :). To answer your second question; I deliberately don't use the designer because the designer is *terrible*. Its not (entirely) Microsoft's fault, its nigh on impossible write a code-generation tool that comes anywhere *near* hand-crafted code. The aforementioned margins are a good example of this. Designer-generated code is almost always absolutely positioned (using margins). This breaks the nano-second your screen is resized. Elements will be off-screen, or extra white-space, etc.

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone With handcrafted code, I can set up the correct containers exactly how I want, with all the right layout properties set, and the layout system in WPF takes care of all those problems for me! It saves me a ton of time manually dragging elements to the right spot and I end up with a much more robust and flexible UI. I came from WinForms. XAML was *extremely* confusing at first, but when i "got" it. When I really understood the power, I would never go back.